# Access class attribute (array) as pointer

Tags: c++

How do you access an attribute of a class that is an array, but not over subscript but as pointer?

I'm implementing software on a mcu and can't easily debug. I want to manipulate the array outside of the class definition using pointers to access entries in the array.

Suppose we have these class definition

```
class foo {
    int fooArray[10];

    int multiplyFirstAndSecondElement() {
        return *(fooArray) * *(fooArray + 1); // this is easy
    }
}

void main {
    foo myFoo;
    myFoo.fooArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    // lets calculate the same result as multiplyFirstAndSecondElement
    int result = *(myFoo.fooArray) * *(myFoo.fooArray + 1);
    int resultInternal = myFoo.multiplyFirstAndSecondElement();
}
```

I would expect `result` and `resultInternal` to have the same value (2).

Comment: `myFoo.fooArray =` - that's not possible. You cannot reassign an array. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: An easy way is making the array public. `public: int fooArray[10];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some basic problems in the code (no arguments for `main`, missing ';' after the class definition and trying to assign an array after its initialization).

To fix the issue of accessing `myFoo.fooArray` outside the class, `fooArray` needs to be declared `public`.

Besides from that, it does not matter whether elements of the array are accessed through a pointer or through subscript. An expression like `*(arr + i)` is exactly equivalent to `arr[i]`.

All in all, you can do the following:

```
class foo {
public:
    int fooArray[10];

    int multiplyFirstAndSecondElement() {
        return fooArray[0] * fooArray[1]; // this is easy
    }
};

int main() {
    foo myFoo = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}};  // Initialize like a struct
    // lets calculate the same result as multiplyFirstAndSecondElement
    int result = myFoo.fooArray[0] * myFoo.fooArray[1];
    int resultInternal = myFoo.multiplyFirstAndSecondElement();
}
```